# C scan open ports on remote server

Tags: c, server, port

I was trying to write a C program that checks for open ports on a remote server.

IMPORTANT: I know there are solutions like nmap or so, but the key here was for me to learn how to program something like this myself.

I have wrote the following code, it gives you a prompt asking for an IP and a Port.

Now there are two solutions:

a) a port number has been entered -> connection to this port will be tested

b) "scan" will gets entered -> every port from 1 to 5000 will be checked for successful connection.

So my problem is, whenever i enter "scan", only Port 21 will be listed as "open".

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define OK 0
#define NO_INPUT 1
#define TOO_LONG 2

static int getLine (char *prmpt, char *buff, size_t sz){

    int ch, extra;

    if (prmpt != NULL) {
        printf("%s", prmpt);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    if (fgets(buff, sz, stdin) == NULL)
        return NO_INPUT;

    if (buff[strlen(buff)-1] != '\n') {
        extra = 0;
        while (((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF)){
            extra = 1;
        }
        return (extra == 1) ? TOO_LONG : OK;
    }

    buff[strlen(buff) - 1] = '\0';
    return OK;
}



int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

int socket_desc;
struct sockaddr_in server;

socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (socket_desc == -1){
    printf("Could not open socket\n");
}

char ip[30];
char port[5];



getLine("IP> ", ip, sizeof(ip));
getLine("Port> ", port, sizeof(port));

if (strcmp("scan", port) == 0){
    puts("scanning....");
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;

    for (int i = 1; i < 5000; i++){
        server.sin_port = htons(i);
        if (connect(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr * )&server, sizeof(server)) < 0 ) {

        }
        else {
            printf("Open port: %d\n", i);
        }



    }


}
else {
int iport = atoi(port);

server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(iport);

if (connect(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr * )&server, sizeof(server)) < 0 )
{
puts("connect error");
return 1;
}

puts("Connected");
}

return 0;

}
```

Why is only the port 21 (FTP) listed as open ? Is it due to the nature of the functions i used, that those are only for data connection (which is port 21 then). Should I use a different function or even maybe a different method (out of my head, maybe ping a port (if possible) instead of trying to connect)

My final goal is to write a program which scans a server and lists the open ports and also what is running on there (SSH, SMTP etc)

thanks for any help!!

Comment: maybe because only port 21 is open on the remote host..? Have you tried a similar scan with nmap? Same/Different results?

Comment: You say it only shows port 21, therefore that's wrong. How do you know that's wrong? Have you proven with other tools that any other ports are open?

Comment: i own the server, i know what ports are open, also nmap showed 30 open ports

Comment: I know you know about `nmap`. A look at the source of a well-developed bit of code, isn't cheating and doesn't prevent you from learning, but sure may save you from making some of the same mistakes that have long since been debugged out of that code `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Once a socket is connected, further attempts to `connect` it are guaranteed to fail with `EISCONN`. You need to create a new socket in each iteration (and don't forget to close it).